# Will Typescript support existing projects with JavaScript libraries?

Tags: typescript

I would like to start using TypeScript in an existing project, but there are already a number of shared JavaScript libraries that I need to use in a TypeScript file. Is there any way for TypeScript to refer to those existing JavaScript libraries with project-related code?

I also tried porting the existing JavaScript libraries to TypeScript and I am getting a lot of compile time errors. It's tough to remove all the compile time errors. Why can't TypeScript just refer those JavaScript classes with a "suppress error and warning" option like Google Dart compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments. I got the perfect answer in the below link

[How to slowly move to / migrate to TypeScript in an existing JavaScript system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349579/how-to-slowly-move-to-migrate-to-typescript-in-an-existing-javascript-system)

Answer (score 10):

There are two cases here:

1. **You are calling JavaScript from TypeScript**

In this regard TypeScript works much like the google closure compiler. Everything needs to be declared before it can be used.

So if you have a separate JavaScript file that has a variable Foo (class, module, number etc), you need to tell TypeScript about it. At its most basic case, you can do something like:

```
declare var Foo: any;
```

Otherwise you will get compile errors.

Later on you can build on this declaration. For third party libraries there is a huge resource available at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

2. **Copying your JavaScript into TypeScript**

An additional thing that might give compile errors is copying over your JavaScript to your TypeScript files. Here TypeScript will help you capture type errors like:

```
var x = '123';
var y = x.toPrecision(4); // Error x is string not a number
```