# How to include typescript in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a node.js with server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

Say I have a typescript t.ts

```
var a = 123;
console.log(a);
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to call the `t.ts` from `server.js` (assume I must use server.js)?
2. Is it possible to convert the `server.js` to `server.ts` (becomes a typescript)?

Comment: you should convert it to js first for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this should be possible if your script exports a class or module. Wrap its functionality in a function, and export it in TS.

```
export function doThing() {
  var a = 123;
}

// server.js:
var doThing = require('t');

doThing();
```

TypeScript uses mostly JavaScript syntax so you can usually just rename the file to .ts and most of it will work, albeit with a few things having unknown types to start with. You may need to just replace the keyword `var` with `import` in your require() lines. I don't think there's an "automatic conversion" program though.

Comment: I really wish I understood this . . .

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) No, node cannot process TypeScript scripts unless you compile `t.ts` to `t.js` first by the TypeScript compiler.

ad 2) TypeScript adds functionality to JavaScript and in many cases you can just rename `file.js` to `file.ts` and you will have valid TypeScript code but there are also cases when you'll get an error - for example:

- Variable reuse

  ```
  var n = 5;  // TypeScript compiler infers that 'n' is a number
  n = "a";    // Error: "a" is not a number!
  ```
- If you target browsers and you use `window` object then you may encounter the following error:

  ```
  var cropper = window.cropper; // throws error: Property 'cropper' does not exist on type 'Window'
  ```

AFAIK there is no conversion tool because the previous examples show that the tool would struggle with error resolving. However, there are [migration](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/02/05/ways-and-advantages-of-migrating-javascript-code-to-typescript/) [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349579/how-to-slowly-move-to-migrate-to-typescript-in-an-existing-javascript-system) from people who went through the process.